# AppBar icons transition through pages

Tags: animation, flutter, dart, icons

How can I implement this transition in flutter?

[image]

I know how to use the appBar and AnimatedIcons widget to make the icon on the left, but I dont really know how to share that icon through pages and reveal other content progressively. Any ideas?

Got the gif from [Material.io](https://material.io/design/iconography/animated-icons.html#transitions)

Answer (score 0):

Use an `AppBar` with typical layout for both screens , this will give users' eyes the effect that the content changed but the app bar remained the same.

Comment: that wasn't the solution I was looking for. I want to learn how could I make that effect on flutter

Answer (score 0):

You can get this from AnimatedIcon widget